# SCSS - Special line break character in content attribute

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using .scss files and compile them.
I have an element with the following css rule:

```
content: attr(data-tooltip) attr(data-tooltip);
```

I'd like to add a line break in the content attribute using `'\A'` but it doesn't work.
When I use this rule:

```
content: attr(data-tooltip) '\A' attr(data-tooltip);
```

it prints the data with a single `'A'` char instead of a line break.

When I use this rule:

```
content: attr(data-tooltip) '\\A' attr(data-tooltip);
```

it prints the content and a `'\\A'` instead of a line break.

When I change the content in the developer console to

```
content: attr(data-tooltip) '\A' attr(data-tooltip);
```

it prints a line break as wanted.

How can I make it add a line break using css?

**EDIT**: This element also has  `white-space: pre-wrap;` rule.

**EDIT**: Seems like it's a [know issue](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/133) of css loader.

Comment: try `content: attr(data-tooltip) '&#13;&#10;' attr(data-tooltip);` or `content: attr(data-tooltip) '&#10;' attr(data-tooltip);`

Comment: Not sure it's a duplicate because I'm using a compiler and the question you posted doesn't;

Comment: @SharonHaimPour it doesn't matter, SCSS doesn't change it at all

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa: I tried but still doesn't work.

Comment: Which tool are you using to compile? in sassmeister works fine: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/c8125ed4b7e35132c175a390d36fbf89

Comment: @blonfu: webpack + css loader.

Comment: You try `attr(data-tooltip) #{"\A"} attr(data-tooltip)`?

Answer (score 0):

```css
[data-tooltip]:after {
  content: attr(data-tooltip) '\A' attr(data-tooltip);
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div data-tooltip="some tooltip text">The DIV</div>
```

Use

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

along with your `\A`.

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using it. Adding it now.

Comment: You do know that `content` afaik is only available on pseudo elements?

Comment: Added a snippet showcasing it's working.

Comment: Your snippet works, but it doesn't work for me.